# Add type to annotation so I can filter Annotation array in the 3 pin colors

Tags: annotations, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, xcode4.6

I'm new to xcode - I made a map and added some Annotations using a MutableArray. I would like to divide them in to 3 groups and show them on the map using the 3 different pin colors.
Hope you can help or give me an url to a guide that can help me. I tried making a 'if statement' and a 'annotationType' but could get it to work right. Hope you can help or give me a hint.

Thank you for your time.

**ViewController.m**

```
{

[super viewDidLoad];

[self.myMapView setDelegate:self];


MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude = AMAR_LATITUDE;
center.longitude = AMAR_LONGITUDE;

MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

myRegion.center = center;
myRegion.span = span;

[myMapView setRegion: myRegion animated: YES];

NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
Annotation *myAnn;
NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
Annotation *myAnn;

myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = TATU_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = TATU_LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Tante Tuli";
myAnn.subtitle =@"Amagerbrogade 161";
[locations addObject:myAnn];
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

MKPinAnnotationView *view =[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"];
view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
view.enabled = YES;
view.animatesDrop = YES;
view.canShowCallout = YES;
view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
return view;
}
```

**Annotation.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
- initWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coords;
@end
```

**Annotation.m**

```
#import "Annotation.h"
@implementation Annotation;
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;
- initWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coords; {
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.coordinate = coords;
}
return self;
}
@end
```

I have tried to add an fourth line:

**Annotation.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString  *colortag;
```

**Annotation.m**

```
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle, colortag;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = TATU.LATITUDE;
location.longitude = TATU.LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"name";
myAnn.subtitle =@"adr";
myAnn.colortag =@"purple";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

if ([[annotation colortag] isEqualToString:@"purple"])
view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
```

I get error: No known instance method for selector 'colertag' :S

Answer (score 0):

Your `Annotation` class has title, subtitle and coordinate properties. Just add a fourth and set it when you're setting the others, then read it and set the colour in viewForAnnotation. You will need to cast the `annotation` parameter into your class (after checking it is an instance of your class and not the user's location annotation) before reading the new property.